# Copying 16 bits to a memory location

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att

I am in a Machine Architecture class in college right now and we are starting to learn assembly. We have a question that says:

> The following x86-64 assembly instruction will copy 16 bits from the A register to the main memory location pointed to by the B  register.

My lab partner thinks the answer is `movw %ax, (%rbx)`.
Because the place we are copying it to is a pointer.

I think it is: `movw %ax, (%bx)`.
Because that signifies that it's 16 bits.

Any explanation will help because we are lost and there's not a ton of explicit information on this!

Comment: Note that you could have just looked at C compiler output for `void foo(short *p) { *p = 1; }` to find out what a store to a 16-bit memory location looks like.

Comment: Related: [Moving two bytes into the lowest portion of a register](//stackoverflow.com/q/58382772) appears to be about a different part of the same lab.  So does [What does this x86-64 assembly code mean/do?](//stackoverflow.com/q/58386753)

Answer (score 2):

**16-bit address-size is not usable in 64-bit code.  Pointers are 64-bit**.  You could have tried assembling `movw %ax, (%bx)`, although the resulting error message, `` foo.s:1: Error: `(%bx)' is not a valid base/index expression `` is not super-helpful.  (I used `gcc -c foo.s` to run GAS on it, on my x86-64 Linux desktop.)

**Address-size and operand-size are separate things.**

`mov %ax, (%rbx)` is a 16-bit store to the memory pointed-to by RBX.  `%ax` is a 16-bit register so it implies 16-bit operand size.  (And yes, `movw` with the operand-size override suffix on the mnemonic is also a valid way of writing it.)

---

Fun fact:
`mov %ax, (%ebx)` is encodable in 64-bit mode, but it will only use the low 32 bits of RBX as the address for the memory operand.  You basically never want to use 32-bit address-size in 64-bit mode, not even in an LEA instruction.

Your lab partner is correct, it's exactly analogous to C:

```
  uint16_t *p;
  sizeof(p) == 8        // With a normal x86-64 C compiler
  sizeof(*p) == 2
```

You always have to use the full size of the register in addressing modes.  Using the low 16 bits of a pointer as the addressing mode wouldn't be useful.

> there's not a ton of explicit information on this!

Intel's manuals are very explicit, but also quite long.  https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm#three-volume

HTML extract of the main part of the vol.2 manual (without the how-to-read-it part): https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/index.html, with the entry for `mov` being https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov

See also other links at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.

Related:

- [data movement error clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50011697/data-movement-error-clarification/50014892#50014892) explains that *(Almost) all x86 instructions require all their operands to be the same size.* with some examples.
- [Is this piece of assembly code invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494285/is-this-piece-of-assembly-code-invalid) shows an attempt to use `(%bl)` as an addressing mode.
- [Why operand must have size in one line but not the other in x86 assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49910109/why-operand-must-have-size-in-one-line-but-not-the-other-in-x86-assembly) when / why you need to specify the operand-size explicitly, like `mov $0, (%rbx)` won't assemble but `movw $0, (%rbx)` will.